# Rejection of FIX order modification: what happens to the original order?

Tags: fix-protocol, trading

Could anyone point me to the relevant section of the FIX spec pertaining to rejected order modification?

Please consider the following scenario:

- A limit order (`NewOrderSingle: ClOrdID='blah.0'`) is placed and
  confirmed as submitted by the broker
- Modification request of the order (`OrderCancelReplaceRequest:
  ClOrdID='blah.1'; OrigClOrdID='blah.0'`) gets rejected due to, say,
  limit violation

What happens to the original order (`ClOrdID='blah.0'`)? Is it still considered valid and can be filled? Does the FIX specification define the expected behavior for such scenarios and the expected state of the original order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**
You should consult your counterparty's FIX specification document(s) for the exact behavior to expect from that specific counterparty when an attempt to replace a working order is rejected.

**Long answer**
Assuming nothing has happened to the original order `11=blah.0` between the time it was placed and the `OrderCancelReplaceRequest` with `11=blah.1|41=blah.0` was sent and rejected (e.g., fill, partial fill(s), external cancel), the original order `11=blah.0` should still be working, and can be filled.

There is nothing in the FIX specification that states the exact expected outcome when an attempt to replace a working order is rejected. Since most exchanges/brokers use some flavor of FIX 4.2, I'll point to the documentation for that version:

> Order Cancel Reject - The order cancel reject message is issued by the
>   broker upon receipt of a cancel request or cancel/replace request
>   message which cannot be honored. Requests to change price or decrease
>   quantity are executed only when an outstanding quantity exists. Filled
>   orders cannot be changed (i.e quantity reduced or price change.
>   However, the broker/sellside may support increasing the order quantity
>   on a currently filled order).

In the message specification it has:

> Tag | Field Name | Req'd | Comments
>
> 39 | OrdStatus | Y | **OrdStatus value after this cancel reject is applied.**

Whatever the counterparty provides for `OrdStatus` in the `OrderCancelReject` message is the state of the original order. I have never run into any counterparty that cancels the original order when a replace request is rejected, but I suppose it's possible. If a counterparty does handle the situation this way, any documentation provided by the counterparty should clearly state so.